# Import ".utils" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from .utils import (
    round_filters,
    round_repeats,
    drop_connect,
    get_same_padding_conv2d,
    get_model_params,
    efficientnet_params,
    load_pretrained_weights,
    Swish,
    MemoryEfficientSwish,
    calculate_output_image_size
)
```

I tried a lot but I could'nt find the solution to fix this error

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, please update your question which will help us understand the issue in a better way - link all the relevant questions you have searched on SO to solve your problem and share the full error traceback as text in a code block in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from .utils import round_filters
```

It gives error: `relative import with no known parent package.` See discussion for this in [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3).

You need to install `EfficientNet-PyTorch` package. About this [package](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/master/efficientnet_pytorch/utils.py)

```
!pip install EfficientNet-PyTorch
```

And add parent package as `from efficientnet_pytorch.utils import round_filters`
So your code should be

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from efficientnet_pytorch.utils import (
    round_filters,
    round_repeats,
    drop_connect,
    get_same_padding_conv2d,
    get_model_params,
    efficientnet_params,
    load_pretrained_weights,
    Swish,
    MemoryEfficientSwish,
    calculate_output_image_size
)
```